# How to change the default temperature from Celcius to Fahrenheit in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, cpu, temperature, system-monitor

I've recently switched from Windows and installed Kubuntu and I was wondering if there was any way to change the CPU temperature in the System Monitor and any widgets to F instead of C? Any help would be appreciated. (I'm a bit new to Linux so apologies for any inconveniences in advance)

Comment: You've not provided your release details (ie. Kubuntu 23.04 or something older?) but I'd expect that to change automatically when you set up your region/locale; have you set that?

Comment: I apologize, I also forgot I even posted this. I am currently on Kubuntu 23.10 and my measurements are set to imperial US.